# extract float numbers from data file

Tags: python, regex, file-io, extract

I'm trying to extract the values (floats) from my datafile. I only want to extract the first value on the line, the second one is the error. (eg. `xo  @  9.95322254_0.00108217853`
 means `9.953...` is value, `0.0010..` is error)

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import re

inf = sys.argv[1]
out = sys.argv[2]
f = inf
outf = open(out, 'w')
intensity = []

with open(inf) as f:    
    pattern = re.compile(r"[^-\d]*([\-]{0,1}\d+\.\d+)[^-\d]*")  

    for line in f:
        f.split("\n")
        match = pattern.match(line)
        if match:
            intensity.append(match.group(0))


for k in range(len(intensity)):
    outf.write(intensity[k])
```

but it doesn't work. The output file is empty.
the lines in data file look like:

```
xo_Is 
xo  @  9.95322254`_0.00108217853
SPVII_to_PVII_Peak_type
PVII_m(@, 1.61879`_0.08117)
PVII_h(@, 0.11649`_0.00216)
I @  0.101760618`_0.00190314017
```

each time the first number is the value I want to extract and the second one is the error.

Comment: `f.split('\n')` will throw an `AttributeError`; the file object doesn't have a `.split()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there, but your code contains errors preventing it from running. The following works:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"[^-\d]*(-?\d+\.\d+)[^-\d]*")  

with open(inf) as f, open(out, 'w') as outf:
    for line in f:
        match = pattern.match(line)
        if match:
            outf.write(match.group(1) + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, one more question. What does this match.group(1) means? I am not a programmer, I'm just using python for data analysis.

Comment: Your pattern contains a capturing group (the text matched between `(` and `)`), the `.group()` method lets you retrieve these from the match. `.group(0)` is the whole match, `.group(1)` is the first group. There are no more capturing groups in your pattern, but if there were you could go on with `.group(2)` for the second, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should test your pattern on a simple string instead of file. This will show where is the error: in pattern or in code which parsing file. Pattern looks good. Additionally in most languages i know group(0) is all captured data and for your number you need to use group(1)
Are you sure that f.slit('\n') must be inside for?